# Change color of NavigationDrawer click color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I would like to know how to change the list item click color of the NavigationDrawer as shown by the arrow in the image from blue to for instance red. 
[image]

My second question is that I would like to add a logo (image), where upon click would direct user to the MainActivity activity at the actionbar (top bar), and below is the activity code that calls the ActionBarActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] mOptionMenu;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mTitleSection;
    private CharSequence mTitleApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mOptionMenu = new String[] { "Opción 1", "Opción 2", "Opción 3" };
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)
         findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
         mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));

         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

         Fragment fragment = null;

         switch (position) {
         case 0:
         fragment = new FirstFragment();
         break;
         case 1:
         fragment = new SecondFragment();
         break;
         case 2:
         fragment = new ThirdFragment();
         break;
         }

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

         mTitleSection = mOptionMenu[position];
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);

         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
         }
         });
         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
         mTitleSection = getTitle();
         mTitleApp = getTitle();

         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
         R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
         R.string.drawer_close) {

         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
             getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }

         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
             getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }
         };

         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ;
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Drawable XML you can do this

Comment: Navigation Drawer != List View inside Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Your first question for Background indicator. it works above API level 11.

navigation_list_background.xml Add your desired colors

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />

</selector>
```

Add to your base style :

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/navigation_list_background</item>

    </style>
```

Add the background to your layout ( which is your item you display in the drawer)

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:text="Option 1" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works.!!

And to your second question. You can use custom action bar.

customactionbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/drawermenu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/actionbarseperator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Yourlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar" />


    <--Your Layout-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Add this in your Java before setcontent

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Add for onclick on the button.

```
   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button:
    ActivityYouwantToOpen.onOpen(v);
        break;
        }
        }
```

Its a long post :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector to change color of pressed states in your mDrawerList. First of all, create a red color solid drawable shape(say redbg) like this in your res/drawable/redbg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

then create a selector say(listviewbg) in res/drawable/listviewbg.xml like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/redbg"/>
</selector>
```

and apply this bg to your mDrawerList in xml

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/mDrawerList "
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:listSelector="@drawable/listviewbg"
/>
```

Comment: and sorry didn't get your second question :(. plz explain a bit